# C++ How to protect oneself from stdio.h macros

Tags: c++, macros

I spent a long time trying to figure out why the following wouldn't compile:

```
enum IPC_RC {OK, EOF, ERROR, NEW };
```

The error message said only something to the effect that it wasn't expecting to see an open parenthesis.  It wasn't until I tried compiling it on a more modern compiler that I learned:

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:201:13: note: expanded from macro 'EOF'
#define EOF     (-1)
```

So I've finally been burned by a macro!  :)

My code doesn't `#include <stdio.h>` (I don't include anything with a .h suffix), but clearly something I included resulted in the inclusion of `<stdio.h>`.  Is there any way (namespaces?) to protect myself, without tracing down exactly where it was included?

Comment: I'd just use a different name, but when it comes down to it, you can #undef it.

Comment: @chris I wouldn't `#undef` it. I would however use a different name since macros are basically a text replace.

Comment: @Rapptz, I wouldn't either.

Comment: I know I can rename it, but I'm concerned about being bitten in a different, equally puzzling way in the future, without my home compiler to reveal the source of the error.  Just wondered if there were a simple way to prevent pollution of the namespace. (If, in fact, that's an accurate description of what's going on.)

Comment: @Chap, Sadly, not easily when dealing with macros.

Comment: Macros are a very primitive mechanism in C/C++. There's no namespacing, like there is for other global identifiers.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense -- since it happens before the compiler gets involved.

Comment: That is why a strong naming convention helps your projects. For example, some prefix for the enumerators, or not using all capital letters (usually macros are all capital letters)...

Comment: Treat all names defined by C++ or C headers that may be implemented as a macro as reserved; do not try to reuse them for your own purposes.  If you do try to reuse them, you will get bitten, especially in C++ where any standard header can include any other standard header (C has rules against doing that, in general). In C, almost any function defined in the library may also have a macro concealing the function — a few functions are explicitly defined to be macros.  Names that cannot be a macro in C++ may be reused with care.

Comment: @dribeas - In the old days of assembler and C, I was strict about prefixing everything.  But I thought namespaces and classes were useful ways of encapsulating a set of names, so one didn't need to use prefixes.  (Although macros, as I've seen, have complete disregard for any such boundaries.)

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces will not be a solution because macros ignore them.

So you have two options:

- get rid of those macros yourself:

  ```
  #ifdef EOF
  #undef EOF
  #endif
  ```
- use a prefix with your enum values:

  ```
  enum IPC_RC
  {
      IPC_OK,
      IPC_EOF,
      IPC_ERROR,
      IPC_NEW
  };
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a satisfactory solution to the problem you describe, but I just wanted to share one way to handle the situation. Every now and then you (have to) use some particularly obnoxious header which redefins a good part of the English language. The X11 headers of `Python.h` come to mind. What I ended up doing - and it worked out very well - is that (usually after I notice the breakage) I wrap the 3rd party header in my own header and deal with the uglyness there.

For instance, in projects which make use of the Ruby interpreter, I usually don't include `ruby.h` directory but rather include an `ourruby.h` file which looks something like this:

```
#ifndef RUBY_OURRUBY_H
#define RUBY_OURRUBY_H

// In Ruby 1.9.1, win32.h includes window.h and then redefines some macros
// which causes warnings. We don't care about those (we cannot fix them).
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  pragma warning(push)
#  pragma warning(disable:4005)
#endif
#include <ruby.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  pragma warning(pop)
#endif

// In Ruby 1.8.7.330, win32.h defines various macros which break other code
#ifdef read
#  undef read
#endif
#ifdef close
#  undef close
#endif
#ifdef unlink
#  undef unlink
#endif
// ...

#endif // !defined(RUBY_OURRUBY_H)
```

That way, I don't have to take care of remembering the fact that some headers are not exactly namespace clean.